# Obtener parametros en una vista CreateView

Tags: python, django

tengo una vista CreateView a la cual le estoy enviando un parametro por url, mi pregunta es ¿como puedo tomar ese parametro para guardarlo en uno de los campos del modelo?

Vista:

```
class ReferenciarSimpatizanteCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Referencia
    template_name = 'referido/form/form.html'
    form_class = ReferidoForm
    page_title = 'Referenciar Simpatizantes'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReferenciarSimpatizanteCreateView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page_title'] = self.page_title
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('simpatizante.refer.list')
```

Form:

```
class ReferidoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
    label_suffix = ':'

    class Meta:
        model = Referencia
        fields = ['referenciador']
        widgets = {
            'referenciador': forms.TextInput(),
        }
```

Modelo:
(el parametro necesito guardarlo en el campo referenciado cuando se envie el formulario )

```
class Referencia(TimeStampedModel):
    referenciador = models.ForeignKey(Simpatizante, related_name="referido_referenciador", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    referenciado = models.ForeignKey(Simpatizante, related_name="referido_referenciado", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    creado_por = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='referido_creado_por', verbose_name=_('creado_por'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    actualizado_por = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='referido_actualizado_por', verbose_name=_('actualizado_por'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('referido')
        verbose_name_plural = _('referidos')
        unique_together = ("referenciador", "referenciado")

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.referenciador.es_lider:
            raise ValidationError({'referenciador': ["Seleccione un lider",]})

        if self.referenciador == self.referenciado:
            raise ValidationError({'referenciado': ["No se puede refenciar el mismo lider ",]})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import datetime

        self.fecha = datetime.datetime.now()

        return super(Referencia, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

URL:

```
url(r'^refer/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(views.ReferenciarSimpatizanteCreateView.as_vi‌​ew()), name="simpatizante.refer")
```

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo estás enviando ese parámetro?

Comment: Hola cesar, por medio de una url

Comment: Pero, ¿de qué manera?, ¿podrías mostrar cómo lo estás haciendo?

Comment: de esta manera @César: 
url(r'^refer/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(views.ReferenciarSimpatizanteCreateView.as_view()), name="simpatizante.refer"),
cuando quiero referir un simpatizante tengo que enviar al modelo el simpatizante referenciador y el simpatizante referenciado, lo que quiero es tomar el id del referenciador que esta en la url y enviarlo al modelo junto con el id del referenciado que se envia desde el formulario

Comment: @MauricioVilla por favor, edita tu pregunta y por como tu llamas la url en el `template` que debería ser algo así como: `{% url 'simpatizante.refer' referido.id %}` todo eso dentro de la etiqueta `a` o donde lo llames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta tu URL:

```
url(r'^refer/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(views.ReferenciarSimpatizanteCreateView.as_vi‌​ew()), name="simpatizante.refer")
```

Deberías poder tener acceso a `pk` desde tu método `get_context_data`:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReferenciarSimpatizanteCreateView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page_title'] = self.page_title
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk') # El mismo nombre que en tu URL
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso depende de como tengas la configuración de la url, si lo que quieres es pasarle por url el id del referenciado sería mas o menos así:

```
url(^'referencia/(?P<id_referencia>[0-9]+)/crear/$', ReferenciarSimpatizanteCreateView.as_view())
```

y en la vista si la petición para crear el modelo lo haces por POST(Que es lo más aconsejable)tendrías que reescribir el método post:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # obtener el id_referencia que se paso por url
    referencia_id = args['id_referencia']
    # obtener la referencia que pertenece a ese id
    referencia = Referencia.objects.get(id=referencia_id)
    # actualizo el modelo y lo salvo
    self.model.referenciador = referencia
    self.save()
    return super(ReferenciarSimpatizanteCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwars)
```

Comment: Hola Reiner, la url la tengo de la siguiente manera:

 url(r'^refer/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(views.ReferenciarSimpatizanteCreateView.as_vi‌​ew()), name="simpatizante.refer"),

y lo que quiero hacer basicamente es tomar esa pk que pertenece a un referenciador y guardarla cuando se  envie el id del referenciado con el formulario, habia pensado hacerlo con el metodo form_valid pero no se como tomar esa pk de la url que le estoy pasando a la vista

Comment: eso esta entro de `self.kwargs`, `kwargs` este es un diccionario, sería algo más o menos así: `pk = self.kwargs['pk']` o `pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)`, en este último caso si `pk` es `None` es porque no tiene ninguna llave con ese valor